# Luke like tool in C#

Tags: lucene, lucene.net, luke

Is there are Luke like tool for viewing lucene indexes in C# using the Lucene.NET api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I could comment to a post, I would here, but...

Bajafresh is correct - you can use the Java version of Luke with indexes built in C# with Lucene.net. I used this approach on a job last year with no troubles. Even dropped Luke on my Program Manager's desktop so she could get a feel for the "new" technology.

Answer (score 4):

Why can't you use the Java version of Luke?  It should be compatible with indexes generated with Lucene.NET

Answer (score 2):

I realize this is an old question. There is an alternative now. Luke.NET available on CodePlex: http://luke.codeplex.com/